# Counting the frequency of a words in Wikipedia

Tags: nlp, wikipedia

I need to extract information from wikipedia, but I have no idea on how to proceed. What I have to do is the following:

Given a word 'w', how can I count the number of times 'w' appears in the whole English Wikipedia? Is there a list already available online? If not, how could I do such thing? I am new to coding and I'm trying to do some experiments in some NLP-related tasks.

Comment: You should tell us at least what tools you are going to use.... Java? C? Some already built application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download the wikipedia dump (in XML format for example)
If you are using a UNIX based OS (ex. LINUX or Mac OS X) you can use grep.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep)

Python can also be used to count occurrences of a specified string in a file
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064565/python-search-text-file-and-count-occurrences-of-a-specified-string)